# Vim: How to open a new tab containing range/selected text from current tab?

Tags: range

I'm in a file and want to copy and edit part of the file content in a new tab temporarily.

I know that I can write it in a file using `:'<,'> w /tmp/list.txt`, then `:tabnew /tmp/list.txt`.

But what if I don't want to write a file and open it afterwards? Do you know a better and/or faster way?

Comment: What is wrong with usual copy/paste? Or do you imply you do not know how to do this?

Comment: Write to a file:  `:w <filename>`, Then use `:tabedit %`?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you want to have range 6, 16 of lines into a new tab buffer:

1. `tabnew`
2. `:call setline(1, getbufline('#', 6, 16))`

Alternate buffer `#` would be set to the buffer you start `tabnew` from.

Or, for example, if you want to "copy" a visual:

```
func! IntoNewTab() abort
    let lines = getline("'<", "'>")
    tabnew
    call setline(1, lines)
endfunc
xnoremap g<C-t> :<C-u>call IntoNewTab()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (as in no mappings or function calls) version of Maxim Kim's answer is

1. Yank the text you want to edit (plenty of ways to do this)
2. `:tabnew`
3. `p`
4. Edit…
5. `:%yank` the modified text back
6. `:tabclose`
7. Put the modified text over top of the original